# How to check if customer password is match

Tags: magento2, customer, password

I have a string variable, and i want to check if this string variable match with the current customer password, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this model

> Magento\Customer\Model\Authentication.php

In this You will find one method **`authenticate($customerId, $password)`**

```
    public function authenticate($customerId, $password)
    {
        $customerSecure = $this->customerRegistry->retrieveSecureData($customerId);
        $hash = $customerSecure->getPasswordHash();
        if (!$this->encryptor->validateHash($password, $hash)) {
            $this->processAuthenticationFailure($customerId);
            if ($this->isLocked($customerId)) {
                throw new UserLockedException(__('The account is locked.'));
            }
            throw new InvalidEmailOrPasswordException(__('Invalid login or password.'));
        }
        return true;
    }
```

You can call this method and pass $customerId, and Password string. If password will be correct then it will return true. Otherwise it will throw an exception.

Comment: when i tried to use that function and insert wrong password, it won't redirect me to normal page instead i got exception page error

Comment: Yes because you see in above code it is throwing an exception. You just need to catch that exception so you will not get any error page Try to add TRY and Catch so you will not get error page.

Comment: i already wrap when calling the function using try&catch, but still it gives an error exception page

Comment: @IdhamChoudry I have need same thing. need to compare new password with exist password. have you get the solution ?